# In QTextEdit how can you detect when user inserts the cursor into the text area only once?

Tags: c++, qt

I have QTextEdit with Text init like :

```
write something here....
```

Now I'd like that the start signal that triggered only once so when the user enter its mouse cursor into the text area the string will removed and the text area will be ready to write. 
I need it to be triggers only once when the widget is up.
I only found the :

```
connect( textEdit, SIGNAL( cursorPositionChanged( int para, int pos ) ), 
         <.....>,  SLOT( Position ( int para, int pos ) ) );
```

but I don't know how to trigger it once , or is it the right way for this.

Answer (score 2):

You could [`disconnect`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#disconnect) that connection in the `Position` slot. That way that slot will only be triggered once.

Another option is simply to keep a boolean in the object that receives the signal that indicates whether or not it should do something when the slot is called.

(You'll probably find yourself wanting to "rearm" that slot. Either call `connect` again, or reset that boolean, depending on what option you chose.)

Answer (score 1):

If your `QTextEdit` widget is only a single line, you might want to consider using a `QLineEdit` widget instead. Then you can call `setPlaceholderText("write something here.... ")` to get the effect you want. [Click here](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#placeholderText-prop) for more info.

Comment: well i used in event filter with bool indicator